# How do i get fscanf reading a file with data separated by ';'?

Tags: c

I am having difficulty using `fscanf`, since I can't read the data from the file while ignoring `;`.

```
void main() {
    int i=0;
    STUDENT aln;
    FILE *fp;


    fp = fopen("Aluno.txt","r");
    //Verificar abertura do File
    checkfile(fp);
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fscanf(fp,"%d%s%d%d%s%d%c\n",&aln.id,&aln.name,&aln.age,&aln.uc.id,&aln.uc.nome,&aln.class.id,&aln.class.name);
        //fscanf(fp, "%d%[^;];[^;];%d%[^;];%d%[^;];%[^;];%d%[^;];%c\n", &aln.id, &aln.name, &aln.age, aln.uc.id, aln.uc.nome, aln.class.id, aln.class.name);
        printf("Nome: %s\n",aln.name);
    }
    system("pause");

}
```

and this is the file content:

```
1;Ruben;15;1;Matematica;1;A
2;Ana;16;2;Portugues;1;A
3;Raquel;17;1;Matematica;2;B
4;Rui;16;2;Portugues;2;B
5;Vasco;15;3;Fisica;3;C
```

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: For a proper [MCVE], please include the expected and actual behavior, not just the input and a code dump. You haven't even explained what's going wrong beyond "having difficulty".

Comment: `if (fscanf(fp, "%d;%[^;];%d;%d;%[^;];%d;%c", ...) != 7) /*error*/;`

Comment: @pmg `%s;` is pretty much guaranteed to fail.

Comment: Thanks @melpomene, edited

Comment: The use of `while(fgets(...) != NULL)` and `strtok` followed by data extraction from the tokens, is one way to tackle the problem.

Comment: We can be fairly confident that passing `&aln.name` where you're expecting `fscanf()` to process a `%s` format is wrong — I can't think of a circumstance in which it would be formally correct.  However, the problem is the type of the pointer, not the value (provided the name element of the `STUDENT` type is an array and not itself a pointer) and things will usually work out OK for you.  Note that the MCVE requested should include the definition of the `STUDENT` structure type.  Also, using `%c` to read `&aln.class.name` is surprising; names usually allow more than one character.

Comment: What result do you want if the line of input is not formed correctly? e.g. `"X;Ruben;15;1;Matematica;1;A"`